# Django auto submits form when page loads

Tags: python, django

I have this form inside my view

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        button_form = TicketSolved(request.POST)
        if button_form.is_valid():
            return redirect('https://google.com')
```

I removed the content and added a redirect to google to test if its still broke.
When the page loads, i automaticly get redirected to google.com, so the form will be submitted automaticly which is bad.

It is a normal form in the HTML Template

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ button_form }}
  <button type="submit">
```

How can I stop the automatic submission of the form when the page loads? Because the form will be actually a button. When someone clicks on the button (the form is valid), following code will be executet:
obj.reopened_counter += 1

```
#            if obj.reopened_counter > 5:
#                obj.ticket_waiting = True
#                obj.ticket_solved = False
#
#            if obj.ticket_waiting == False and obj.ticket_solved == True:
#                obj.ticket_waiting = True
#                obj.ticket_solved = False
#            else:
#                obj.ticket_waiting = False
#                obj.ticket_solved = True
#            obj.save()
```

So everytime someone clicks the button in the form, the counter will go +1. But even if the user just reloads the page, the counter will go up +1 because of this *auto-submit-when-loading-view* problem.

Comment: Why does it auto submit ? Do you have any javascript that on page load triggers the form button ? Otherwise it should only work when button is clicked not on reload.